# проблема с фоном

Tags: css

Почему картинка не отображается на фоне, а отображается один градиент?

```css
 .signup {
  background:linear-gradient(93.01deg, #BE30D2 6.8%, #7188F7 99.21%), url('../img/benefits/signup background.svg')-30px no-repeat ;}
```

Comment: ну мож нет такой картинки

Comment: она отображается без градиента

Comment: `background: url('../img/benefits/signup background.svg') -30px no-repeat, linear-gradient(93.01deg, #BE30D2 6.8%, #7188F7 99.21%);`

Comment: А почему в вопросе написано "отображается один градиент", а в комментарии "без градиента"? Как это все понять?

Answer (score 0):

В путе до картинки есть пробел

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос